# Query from tables where the table names are stored on a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `schemas`, it has:

- unique_id (varchar) - contains table names
- data (text)

each `unique_id` on the `schemas` rows has a table with similar columns, for example: `users` (id, data), `holidays` (id, data), etc..

Is it possible to query from those tables without typing one by one?

```
CREATE TABLE schemas (
  unique_id VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY, // table names stored here
  data TEXT
);
INSERT INTO schemas VALUES('users','foo'),('holidays','bar');
-- not just users and holidays, there are many more..  

CREATE TABLE users ( 
  id BIGSERIAL,
  data TEXT
);
INSERT INTO users(data) VALUES('user1'),('user2'); 

CREATE TABLE holidays (
  id BIGSERIAL,
  data TEXT
);
INSERT INTO holidays(data) VALUES('hol1'),('hol2');
-- and so on, if a record added to the schemas, 
--   a new table created with unique_id name
```

Is it possible to do a single query without `PL/*` that could give a result something like this:

```
schema_unique_id | schema_data | table_data
users            | foo         | user1
users            | foo         | user2
holidays         | bar         | hol1
holidays         | bar         | hol2
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But: if your table- or column names are variables you'll need dynamic SQL. (which *at least* implies plpgsql)

Comment: There is no way to _dynamically_ generate SQL without some sort of non-SQL programming - whether that's PL/* or a program talking to your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's typically not possible without dynamic SQL. But, with your specified use-case, it can be realized using [inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html):

```
CREATE TABLE schemas (
  unique_id VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY, 
  data TEXT
);
INSERT INTO schemas VALUES('users','foo'),('holidays','bar');

CREATE TABLE mydata (
  id BIGSERIAL,
  data text
);

CREATE TABLE users ( ) INHERITS (mydata);
INSERT INTO users(data) VALUES('user1'),('user2'); 

CREATE TABLE holidays ( ) INHERITS (mydata); 
INSERT INTO holidays(data) VALUES('hol1'),('hol2');

SELECT s.unique_id, s.data as schema_data, d.data as table_data
FROM schemas s, mydata d, pg_class
WHERE d.tableoid = pg_class.oid AND s.unique_id = pg_class.relname;

 unique_id | schema_data | table_data 
-----------+-------------+------------
 holidays  | bar         | hol1
 holidays  | bar         | hol2
 users     | foo         | user1
 users     | foo         | user2
(4 rows)
```

`SELECT`ing from the parent table causes PostgreSQL to `UNION` the rows of the parent with queries of those inherited columns from each of the child tables.

If your tables are already compatible with the inheritance model, you can `ALTER` them to introduce it:

```
ALTER TABLE users INHERIT mydata;
```